# setting up turtle environment, getting AttributeError on Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, turtle-graphics

I have tried to run turtle code in Jupyter, and I get the error:

`AttributeError: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'forward'`

I am able to get a turtle window to run with the same code on PyCharm and Spyder. Can anyone give me the steps on how to set up Jupyter to get turtle module to run? Is there a way to easily configure environment for turtle and Jupyter from Anaconda Navigator?

note: PyCharm interpreter is python, and Spyder was installed through Anaconda and interpreter is set to: "default ie same as Spyder's".

Thanks in advance.

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
jack = turtle.Screen()
jack.forward(150)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be a problem with the environment. The `forward` attribute does not exist for a `Screen` object. What you meant to do was something like:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(640,320)
wn.bgcolor("lightblue")
jack = turtle.Turtle()
jack.forward(30) #move jack forward by 30
turtle.done()
```

The `forward` attribute works with an instance of the `Turtle` class. This code works on all environments including Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks--must have mixed up code, switching apps. Do you have further insight on making customizations to turtle, such as screen size - all within Jupyter? tia.

Comment: Disregard: I'm seeing in python docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.window_width "turtle.window_width() turtle.window_height()
Both are replicas of the corresponding TurtleScreen methods" depracated and is now screensize() as per https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.screensize, ie  screen.screensize(2000,1500)

Comment: Yes, those are deprecated methods. I've just edited my code to set screen size with `wn.setup()`. I also added a nice background color as bonus. If this answer was helpful, you may accept it :).